# Emoji's on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: emoji

Can you get emojis on ubuntu? Preferably without having to download a whole load of stuff. I have seen other answers but none that make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

found this package

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

from http://ubuntuguide.net/add-emoji-support-in-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04

got black/white emoji, in text-editor & terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Basic emoji support(black and white) is enabled by installin the Symbola fonts package. If is not already installed in your system open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install fonts-symbola
```

Browsers like Google Chrome (Chromium?) and Firefox should be able to show web emoji fonts.

**Edit**: while firefox web font emoji support was suposedly introduced in Firefox 50, some users claim they don't show while others clame they do.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/firefox-50-brings-native-emoji-linux-desktops

Comment: How do i use these emojis